# use of std:swap (in implementation of assignment operator)

Tags: c++, class, std

I have seen in some place an implementation of assignemt operator of class matrix looks like this:

```
class Matrix
{
private:

    int rows;
    int cols;
    int **mat;

public:

    Matrix& operator=(const Matrix& m)
        {
            if ( this != &m )
            {
                Matrix temp(m);
                std::swap(temp.rows, rows);
                std::swap(temp.cols, cols);
                std::swap(temp.mat, mat);
            }
            return *this;
        }
}
```

Now, suppose I want to use swap function for that matter , what is the alternative way to use it without writing `std:swap`? Am I suppose in such case to build a friend-function that implementing swap of two matrix?

Comment: This doesn't look right.  It should be [copy and swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom), not pass by reference and swap.

Comment: @NathanOliver: from a quick glance, this should be functionally equivalent, it still performs the copy but only after checking for self-assignment (not needed for correctness, but can be seen as a tiny extra optimization - or a pessimization of the common case). Still, it's more code (4 lines and two tokens extra) for no good reason.

Comment: @MatteoItalia It is not functionally equivalent.  In copy and swap you steal the guts of a temporary copy.  When you pass by reference it steals the guts of the object itself and in this case it actually wont work as it is `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: it is still creating the temporary from which the guts are stolen, only inside the `if (this != &m)` block instead of having it implicitly created by receiving the argument by copy.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Ah, yep, missed that in the if block.

Comment: Mind you, this is still worse than the usual copy & swap in case `Matrix` had a move constructor; in general, if you have a move constructor and a "copy and swap" assignment operator you get move assignment for free (as an rvalue reference can be used to move-construct the `operator=` argument, which is then swapped over the assignment target by `operator=`); here instead you'd have to implement move assignment on its own.

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom

Comment: @MatteoItalia that is true for C++11 and later. Passing the input param by value allows efficient copying and moving. That was not the case prior to C++11, when passing the parameter by reference was preferred.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: in the general case of course I agree, but even in C++03 the copy & swap idiom to implement the assignment operator was generally implemented using a by-value parameter for `operator=`, to leverage the implicit copy required to instantiate it. Of course that makes impossible to have a self-assignment elision optimization (the copy constructor is always invoked, unlike in OP variant), which, for a matrix class, may actually be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, suppose I want to use swap function for that matter , what is the alternative way to use it without writing `std:swap`? Am I suppose in such case to build a friend-function that implementing swap of two matrix?

You have to swap the two `Matrix` objects. Whether you do it in the `operator=` function or another function is secondary.

As a matter of practice, I would recommend creating a function that swaps two `Matrix` objects and use it the implementation of the `operator=` function. You have various options for that.

1. Make it a non-member `friend` function.
2. Make it a `static` member function.
3. Make it a non-`static` member function.

I would probably pick a `static` member function but I don't see any downsides to using one of the other two.

One thing to note is that you will end up using `std::swap` to swap the member variables of the `Matrix` objects in that function. It came across to me as though that is a concern for you.